# javascript arrays - splicing and pushing on an eventlistener

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling with some JavaScript homework. We have to assign a random number to the card when the page loads. And when you click a card, it should push it to the end of the array. My main issue is creating a temporary variable and storing the element that is clicked.

**The HTML:**

```
<fieldset id="cards-area">
  <legend>Hand of cards</legend>
  <div class="hand-of-cards" id="cards">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <button id="sort-cards" type="button">Sort</button>
  <button id="reverse-cards" type="button">Reverse</button>
</fieldset>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
(function () {
    var cardElements, cardValues;

    // WRITE CODE HERE TO MAKE THE #cards ELEMENT WORK
    //This makes all the div elements an element
    cardElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#cards div'));

    //This creates an empty array to store elements into
    cardValues = [];

    cardElements.forEach(function (cardElement) {
        // Gives the card elements a random number when the page loads
        cardElement.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1;

        //This pushes the card elements into the array
        cardValues.push(cardElement);

        //Event listener when the card element is clicked it
        //stores that card element into a variable
        //splices that cardElement
        //and pushes that cardElement to the end which was stored into a variable
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var whichCard = cardValues.indexof(cardElement);
            cardValues.splice(whichCard, 1);
            cardValues.push(whichCard);
        }, false);
    });
}());
```

Comment: Can you please explain more specifically, what the problem is?

Comment: I want to be able to click one of the card elements and that card element is moved to the end of the array. When I click, nothing happens. What I need to do is when a card element is clicked, it stores it as a temporary variable, splices the element that is clicked, and pushes the temporary variable.

Comment: I think you may have meant to use `cardValues.push(cardElement);` and not `cardValues.push(whichCard);` Also, you're not updating the DOM anywhere, you're just updating an array.

Comment: I have the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { at the very beginning of my entire code, do I have to update it again?

Comment: The [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) only fires once. The reason to use that is to make sure elements render on the page before you query them in JS. You don't need that at all if you stick the `<script>` element for your JS right before the closing `</body>` tag (so that it only loads after all the preceding html renders).

Comment: If you want more help, you should include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Check it out. If you try to click on any number it will push it to the end of the array.

```js
(function () {
    var cardElements, cardValues;

    // WRITE CODE HERE TO MAKE THE #cards ELEMENT WORK
    //This makes all the div elements an element
    cardElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#cards div'));

    //This creates an empty array to store elements into
    var cardValues = [];

    cardElements.forEach(function (cardElement) {
        // Gives the card elements a random number when the page loads
        cardElement.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1;

        //This pushes the card elements into the array
        cardValues.push(cardElement);

        //Event listener when the card element is clicked it
        //stores that card element into a variable
        //splices that cardElement
        //and pushes that cardElement to the end which was stored into a variable
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var varNumber;
            //var whichCard = cardValues.indexof(cardElement);
            for(i = 0;i<cardValues.length;i++){
              if(cardValues[i] == this){
                //console.log(i);
                varNumber = i;
              }
            }
            var whichCard = cardValues[varNumber];
            //console.log(whichCard);
            cardValues.splice(varNumber,1)
            cardValues.push(whichCard);
            
            document.getElementById("cards").innerHTML = "";
            
            for(i = 0;i<cardValues.length;i++){
                //console.log(cardValues[i]);
                document.getElementById("cards").innerHTML += cardValues[i].outerHTML;
            }
            
        }, false);
    });
}());
```

```html
<fieldset id="cards-area">
  <legend>Hand of cards</legend>
  <div class="hand-of-cards" id="cards">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <button id="sort-cards" type="button">Sort</button>
  <button id="reverse-cards" type="button">Reverse</button>
</fieldset>
```

:)